# How to request UAC Elevation within Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, admin, python-3.9

My Python script requires administrator privileges, however I cannot seem to get it working. I want it to be able to request admin privileges but also work when the file is compiled by pyinstaller too.

I tried this:

```
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it requests admin but does nothing with it.
I am using python version 3.9.9 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/605012/784839)

Essentially, you can tell PyInstaller to embed a manifest file, and that manifest file can let Windows know to request UAC.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```